# How to disable the full/half keyboard shortcut in chewing

Tags: shortcut-keys, ibus

I use the chewing input method, which when enabled includes a keyboard shortcut (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd>) for toggling between full- and half-width character modes.  I often trigger this keyboard shortcut by accident.  How can I disable this <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd> shortcut?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. Open Ubuntu "Settings";
2. Click the "Keyboard Shortcuts" option;
3. Add new custom shortcut, more details below:

   **Name**: Remove full-width switching
   **Command**:  echo ""
   **Shortcut**: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>

   [image: Set custom shortcut dialog]

Then, test if it works.